# WebDriver Visual Studio 2010 and ReSharper APPCRASH

Tags: c#, firefox, nunit, webdriver, resharper

We use Visual Studio 2010 with ReSharper to handle and to run our webdriver (2.25.1) tests. Whenever I launch my test the browser (Firefox 12) starts but after a few second I got a window "Task runner Application has stopped working" and the details part contains this:

In this case:
Firefox: 12.0.0
NUnit: 2.5.10 (bundled with ReSharper)
Visual Studio: 2010
WebDriver: 2.25.1

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: JetBrains.ReSharper.TaskRunner.CLR4.MSIL.exe
  Application Version:  6.1.37.86
  Application Timestamp:    4ef0c42d
  Fault Module Name:    clr.dll
  Fault Module Version: 4.0.30319.269
  Fault Module Timestamp:   4ee9d6e1
  Exception Code:   c00000fd
  Exception Offset: 0000000000008daa
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.4
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: d161
  Additional Information 2: d161e6195854b08ee25ee662a5207f62
  Additional Information 3: ffbe
  Additional Information 4: ffbe17c9618e32bb213796ac6f7261de
```

I already have tried to change NUnit and Webdriver version but the result is the same.

When I use different firefox (7.0.1) I got this:
Firefox: 7.0.1
NUnit: 2.5.10 (bundled with ReSharper)
Visual Studio: 2010
WebDriver: 2.25.1

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: plugin-container.exe
  Application Version:  7.0.1.4288
  Application Timestamp:    4e83b8cd
  Fault Module Name:    NPSWF32_11_3_300_271.dll
  Fault Module Version: 11.3.300.271
  Fault Module Timestamp:   502701bf
  Exception Code:   c0000005
  Exception Offset: 002fba12
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.4
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 0a9e
  Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Additional Information 3: 0a9e
  Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789

Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\WINDOWS\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
```

I also tried to change the version of ReSharper but the result is the same.

So, I assume that the root cause somwhere between webdriver and firefox but I don't have a clue what should/can I do. Does anyone have any idea how it is possible to workaround or fix it because, at the moment, I can not do my job.

Thanks in advance!